# How To Form this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, union

I want to create a MySQL Query similar to

```
SELECT city, state, country FROM location 
UNION 
SELECT 'Chicago','Illinois', 'USA' IF 'Chicago' NOT IN (SELECT city FROM location);
```

Basically, if 'Chicago' is not returned in the results, I want to append it to the results. Problem is, the query expects a `FROM` table. Do I use a dummy table, or am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Can you paste table structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write the second `SELECT` with no conditions and let the `UNION` do the work for you. `UNION` will remove duplicates from the result set, so there's no harm in repeating "Chicago" in the second query. If "Chicago" also occurs in your first `SELECT`, the `UNION` will remove the duplicate created by your second query.

```
SELECT city, state, country FROM location 
UNION 
SELECT 'Chicago','Illinois', 'USA'
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?

Comment: (I am not the downvoter) This doesn't exactly work because if Chicago already exists in the first select statement, it will show up 2 times - once from the first select statement and once from the second select statement. It does this even if I use UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: @Chris: The only way I could see this not working is if the state and country columns contain different values for the two city "Chicago" listings. Is that the case?

Comment: Thank You. There is apparently a problem with the State field but this solution does work.